# Could not determine data type of parameter $1

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have this add friend API for the back-end of Android Studio App and whenever I run it, the app display the error "Could not determine data type of parameter $1". So far I have tried casting it to int as in the code down below (maybe my syntax is wrong) but the error still persists.

Here's the code:

```
router.post("/add", (request, response, next) => {
console.log("User " + request.decoded.memberid + " Add " + request.body.userName)
if (!request.body.userName) {
    response.status(400).send({
        message: "Missing required information"
    })
} else {
    next()
}}, (request, response) => {
let check = 'SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE MemberID_A = $1::int AND MemberID_B = (SELECT MemberID FROM Members WHERE Username = $2)'
let check2 = 'SELECT * FROM Members WHERE Username = $2'
let query = 'INSERT INTO Contacts (MemberID_B, MemberID_A) VALUES ($1::int, (SELECT MemberID FROM Members WHERE Username = $2))'
let query2 = 'INSERT INTO Contacts (MemberID_A, MemberID_B, Verified) VALUES ($1::int, (SELECT MemberID FROM Members WHERE Username = $2), 2)'
let values = [request.decoded.memberid, request.body.userName]
let values1= [request.body.userName]

pool.query(check2, values1).then(result => {
    if (result.rowCount == 0) {
        response.status(404).send({
            message: "Contact does not exist"
        })
    } else {
        pool.query(check, values).then(result => {
            if (result.rowCount > 0) {
                response.status(404).send({
                    message: "This username is in your contact"
                })
            } else {
                pool.query(query, values)
                pool.query(query2, values)
                response.send({
                    success: true
                })
            }
        }).catch (error => {
            response.status(400).send({
                message: "SQL Error 1",
                error: error
            })
        })
    }
}).catch (error => {
    response.status(400).send({
        message: "SQL Error 2 " + error,
        error: error
    })
})
```

})

Thank you!!!

Comment: check out this to see if it is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170842/could-not-determine-data-type-of-parameter-1-in-python-pgsql/12170946

Comment: Which of the statements is failing?

Comment: It didn't tell me for sure but could be any of these 3 (query, query2, check).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quote

```js
let check = 'SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE MemberID_A = "$1"::int'
```

Comment: I tried that but it's still giving me the same error

Comment: Actually it works now, I was running the query against value with 2 variables inside so $1 wasn't used hence the error